# how to pass viewmodel in to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a viewmodel called "PlanObjectsViewModel". I need to add results inside of my while loop to an instance of PlanObjectsViewModel.I tried following approach..Is that wrong?? I'm getting an exception called;

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `'MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel'`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel]'.

```
var model2 = model1.GroupBy(t => t.Type).Select(g => new PlanBaseTypedObjects
{
    Id = g.Key,
    ObjectDetails = g
});

int Type1 = 0;
int Type2 = 0;        

double? temp = 0;

foreach (var item in model2)
{
    if(item.Id==1)
        Type1 = item.ObjectDetails.Count();

    if (item.Id == 2)
        Type2 = item.ObjectDetails.Count();
}

Random rand = new Random();

var final = new PlanObjectsViewModel(); // want to add data to this view model

while (budget > temp)
{
    if (Type1 != 0) {
        int randi = rand.Next(0, Type1);

        foreach (var item in model2)
        {
            if (item.Id == 1) { foreach (var x in item.ObjectDetails) {
                if (x.Id == randi)
                    final.Id = x.Id;// i don't know,whether this is a correct way to 
                                    //add data row to the model
                temp=temp+x.Price;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Type2 != 0)
    {
        int randi = rand.Next(0, Type2);

        foreach (var item in model2)
        {
            if (item.Id == 2)
            {
                foreach (var x in item.ObjectDetails)
                {
                    if (x.Id == randi)
                        final.Id = x.Id;
                    temp = temp + x.Price;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return View(model1);
```

In my view i have;

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel>
```

can anyone explain why is that?? if i'm doing it it a wrong way,what is the best approach??Thank you.

Comment: What type is model1? The error says it's a single value and not enumerable.

Comment: What's the point of doing the looping and calculations with `model2` if you pass `model1` to the view in the end?

Comment: Sorry!! final is the one to pass to the view..not model1

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva the type of `final` is `PlanObjectsViewModel`, so why do you have `@model IEnumerable<MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel>` in your view?

Comment: @ekad is that correct the way i used to enter data for "final" inside the while??

Comment: That depends on your view code. Please add your view code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting a collection but you pass in an individual item to the view instead.

`MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel` = object
`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel]` = collection of objects

Change this

`@model IEnumerable<MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel>`

to

`@model MvcApp.ViewModel.PlanObjectsViewModel`